# Theory Of Numbers question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have the equation:

x=1
now, multiplying L.H.S and R.H.S with 'x' I get;

x<sup>2</sup>=x

This equation has the roots x=0 and x=1 now if I again multiply with 'x' I get;

x<sup>3</sup>=x<sup>2</sup>

This equation has the roots x=0 and x=0 and x=1.

I understand that if x is equal to 0 then repeatedly multiplying with x will give me solutions but why can't  x be equal to 1?? for if I continue multiplying with 1 my equation remains correct ???

Comment: $0\times x=0\times y$ does not mean that $x=y$...

Comment: Well multiplying by 0 somehow mutitliates the equation

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an equality $\rm a=b$ and you apply some transformation to both sides correctly, the resulting equation will be true if the first one was. However, the converse is not true: there are *irreversible* transformations (or transformations that are only reversible under special conditions), and after applying these the resulting equation will *not* be logically equivalent to the original one.

Take, for example, $\rm x=1$. If you multiply both sides by $\rm 0$, you get $\rm 0=0$, which is of course true but does not say anything at all about the value of $\rm x$, let alone that it is equal to $\rm 1$. It is often the case that with polynomials and radicals, some of our transformations (like squaring) will introduce *more* solutions than the equation originally had, and these must be evaluated and discarded in the final analysis.

In your case, going from $\rm x=1$ to $\rm x^2=x$ introduces the false solution $\rm x=0$ (I say it is false because it is clearly incompatible with $\rm x=1$ in any familiar setting), and we must discard it in order to keep our analysis consistent with our original hypothesis.